# Convert the locations to pages and then compute the average sentiment in each page. Plot that average score by page

Tags: r, text-mining

Need help with 9. But I've included the relevant code.

5. We will later make a plot of sentiment versus location in the book. For this, it will be useful to add a column with the word number to the table.

```
words <- words %>% 
  mutate(word_num = 1:length(word))
head(words)
```

6. Remove the stop words and numbers from the words object. Hint: use the anti_join.

```
data("stop_words")
words_clean <- words %>% 
  anti_join(stop_words) %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(word,"^\\d+$"))
head(words_clean)
```

7. Now use the AFINN lexicon to assign a sentiment value to each word.

```
library(textdata)
afinn <- get_sentiments("afinn")
words_sentiments <- words_clean %>% 
  inner_join(afinn, by = "word")  
head(words_sentiments)
```

8. Make a plot of sentiment score versus location in the book and add a smoother.

```
library(ggplot2)
words_sentiments %>% ggplot(aes(x= word_num, y=value)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth()
```

9. Assume there are 300 words per page. Convert the locations to pages and then compute the average sentiment in each page. Plot that average score by page. Add a smoother that appears to go through data.

```
# word_sentiments2 <- words_sentiments %>% 
  cut(words_sentiments$word_num,seq(1,max(words_sentiments$word_num), by=300))
word
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `page_number` we use ceiling of the quotient, then we `group_by` the `page_number` and summarise the values

```r
words_sentiments %>%
  mutate(page_number = ceiling(word_num / 300)) %>%
   group_by(page_number) %>%
    summarise(average=mean(value)) -> summed
summed %>%  ggplot(aes(x=page_number, y=average)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
```